# Связка checkbox и картинку excel

Tags: excel

Private Sub Флажок1_Click()

```
If Флажок1.Value = True Then
Картинка1.Visible = False
Картинка2.Visible = True
Else
Картинка1.Visible = True
Картинка2.Visible = False
End If
End Sub
```

Почему это может не работатать?

Answer (score 0):

Картинка - это элемент коллекции:

```
Private Sub Флажок1_Click()
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes
        .Range(Array("Картинка1")).Visible = Not Флажок1.Value
        .Range(Array("Картинка2")).Visible = Флажок1.Value
    End With
End Sub
```